# Firebase validation works quite unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have following firebase validation:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "companies": {
      ".write": "newData.exists()", 
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren([
          'companyName',
        ])",
        "companyName": { 
          ".validate": "newData.isString()" 
        },                          
      }
    }
  }
```

And following **JSON**:

```
const r = { companyName: "exampleName" }
```

When I start the simulation in firebase console at `console.firebase.google.com` everything goes smooth - the simulation ends up with a success. However, when I try to submit my data with simple function it **always** rejects the request.
`Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied`

The logic responsible for it is quite simple:

```
const companyRef = firebase.database().ref('companies').push();

companyRef.set(r, (err) => {  
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);       //   <-------- always appears :/
   }
})
```

**Note**: Also **very interesting** fact is that if I remove my `validate` part from `firebase rules`, I can upload the data without any problems... So I think that this is something weird about the validation...

Loooking forward for any help. Thanks:)

**Edit**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "companies": {
      "$companyId": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true, 
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren([
          'companyEmail',  
          'companyName',
        ])",
        "companyEmail": { 
          ".validate": "newData.isString()" 
        },
        "companyName": { 
          ".validate": "newData.isString()" 
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you call `push()` you generate a new location under `companies`. But your rules validate on `/companies` itself, so will always fail.

Instead you should move your validation rules one level down in the tree. I'll look up a recent answer I gave for the same problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, Frank. However - the main root (in my case `companies`) goes before `$childid` or after it?

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "companies": { "$companyId": { ".read": true, ...`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Frank, I've edited my question. I dont know if im just basically dumb or what but it still doesn't want to work properly... It even does not start to validate, but refuses to write the data at the beginning...

Comment: The new rules you posted look better. It's hard to say what's going wrong with the code though. Please replace the `r` with the minimal hard-coded JSON with which you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But even the simulation doesn't want to start... it says - `write - simulation rejected`

Comment: Same problem: without seeing what you're trying to write where it'll be hard to say more.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Provided image directly from the firebase console, it's in polish but I believe you will be able to understand it easily

Comment: Thanks for that screenshot. You're writing to `/offers` where you've made the write invalid, because I told you to (and I think it's what you want). The console does not automatically call `push()`. To simulate that, write to `/offers/-MyFakePushId` or something like that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Works like a charm, thank you!!!